# Why does building an R package stop my code from working?

Tags: r, build, package

**It seams that upon installing my custom R package code stops to work? Why?**

In detail, I have a tiny R package [`goEnrichment`](https://github.com/asishallab/goEnrichment) (click to see the Github repo). The R package includes just just two functions and some binary data.
Also there are two test R-scripts that I run after installing the R package with `R CMD INSTALL goEnrichment`. One test script fails while the other works.

The only difference between the two scripts is that in the working version I `require` the necessary libraries and `source` the functions file manually, while in the other failing script I `require` my `goEnrichment` library directly.
Note, that both scripts are started directly from their directory `goEnrichment/exec`.

Start the **working** test with `cd goEnrichment/exec && Rscript testGoEnrichment_works.R`. Excerpt:

```
# This is the WORKING version
require(GOstats)
require(GSEABase) 
require(RMySQL)
source( "../R/goEnrichment.R" )
```

Start the **failing** test script with `cd goEnrichment/exec && Rscript testGoEnrichment_fail.R`. Excerpt:

```
# This version FAILS
require(goEnrichment)
```

The error I get is somewhat uninformative to me:
`'dimnames' applied to non-array`.

The `built` R package fails on two platforms, that is on `Debian Wheezy 64` with `R 3.0.2` and on `Mac OS X Yosemite` with `R 3.1.1`.

I really have no clue why this happens. I checked for file format and unexpected characters using `Vim`. The cause does not seem to be the `DESCRIPTION` file either, because all libraries, `goEnrichment` depends on, are imported.

Does any one have a clue what causes this very weird error? Help will be much appreciated.

Comment: You don't have any of the functions you import in your NAMESPACE file.  That may be the cause.  You're using roxygen2 so using `packageName::function` in your functions should add them to the NAMESPACE when you document/build.

Comment: Thank you Tyler for your effort. Unfortunately that did not the trick, I switched to using `packageName::function` in my function, but still get the error. By the way after `R CMD INSTALL goEnrichment` the NAMESPACE file is still unchanged. - Any ideas?

Comment: Did you push the changes to GitHub?  Did you rerun `document` or what ever you use to turn the roxygen output into the correct documentation?

Comment: Dear Tyler, sorry, I had forgotten to push to Github. I have done it now. I did rerun `roxygen2::roxygenise()`which did not touch the `NAMESPACE` file.

Comment: In the meantime I found out, that one has to delete the NAMESPACE file to have Roxygen2 generate it. I did so and added the appropriate `import` and `export` fields. The error persists unfortunately. I pushed everything to Github. Do you have any ideas left?

Comment: Throw a browser in the code so you can snoop around or use another R debugging tool incuding: http://www.milanor.net/blog/?p=817  You have to isolate the error.  Your data isn't in the shape you expect it to be.

Answer (score 0):

After much testing I found the source of the problem.

For some reason when requiring my package with

`require(goEnrichment)`

the generic function

`summary.GOHyperGResult`

is not loaded, as it should be. The method however is available when the packages, `goEnrichment` depends upon, are required manually. As to why this is, I had no time to investigate. I believe the here reported error is related to this [bug](https://support.bioconductor.org/p/34347/).

Thanks to Tyler for your efforts, very much!